# Периодическое обновление ListView

Tags: listview, java

Привет всем!

Есть задача вывести на экран список, данные берутся с сервера, а потом с какой-то периодичностью обновлять его с сервера.

Список есть, при создании активити он загружается и отображается:

```
    GSMGPSSender.getList();//Это обновление данных в базе с сервера

    // формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_SLCT, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_TXT, DB.COLUMN_STS1, DB.COLUMN_STS2, DB.COLUMN_STS3, DB.COLUMN_STS4, DB.COLUMN_STS5, DB.COLUMN_STS6, DB.COLUMN_STS7 };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ivSlct, R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvText, R.id.ivSts1, R.id.ivSts2, R.id.ivSts3, R.id.ivSts4, R.id.ivSts5, R.id.ivSts6, R.id.ivSts7 };

    // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);

    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Сделал для начала обновление при нажатии кнопки, работает правильно:

```
public void onButton1Click(View view) {
      GSMGPSSender.getList();//Это обновление данных в базе с сервера
      getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();//обновляем список на экран
  }
```

Для того чтобы обновлять данные раз в минуту, сделал TimerTask, вот ее запуск:

```
t.schedule(new GetPosTask(), new Date(0), 60000);
```

А вот сам таск:

```
class GetPosTask extends TimerTask {
    public static final String TAG = GetPosTask.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        GSMGPSSender.getList();//Обновление данных в базе вроде работает
        }
}
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой - как обновить данные на экране? Функция, которая обновляет данные на экране:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();//обновляем список на экран
```

из TimerTask не может быть вызвана, ругается там на нее.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обновить экран из TimerTask?

Comment: @Ujin778, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Ujin778, работает? :)

Answer (score 1):

Я, может, по-другому мыслю или не мыслю Вашу программу, и что Вы в точности делаете, но я бы так писал примерно:

```
ObservableList<String> serversRootList;
String[] serverListFromWeb;

...

ListView<String> servers = new ListView(serversRootList);

//Получаете новый список серверов по таймеру.
watchDogTimer = new Timer();  
watchDogTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {

  serverListFromWeb = getServersFromWeb();
  serversRootList.clear();

  //Перезаполняете serversRootList и обновляем список
  for(String server: serverListFromWeb){
   serversRootList.add(server);
  }

 }
}, 1000, (60*1000)*2);

//Обновили список в том числе на экране.
```

Конечно, я бы заменил String на свой класс и еще добавил бы cellFactory, чтобы выводить полный спектр данных и просто, чтобы все выглядело приятнее. Код, конечно, можно переделать, обойтись без промежуточного serverListFromWeb, но для наглядности оставим пока.